# Images Clipped During Runtime

Tags: wpf

This is what it should look like:

[image: Image that I made]

When I run the program, my images are clipped.

[image: Image displayed]

XAML:

```
<Grid>
<Image Source="Assets/无装饰背景.png" x:Name="BackGround">
</Image>
<Image Source="Assets/背景光效.png" x:Name="BackGround_Effect"  ></Image>
<Image Source="Assets/搜索药品.png" Margin="159,269,1322,218" Width="436" Height="593" Stretch="Fill"/>
<Image Source="Assets/慢病管理.png" Width="436" Height="593" Margin="631,269,853,218" Stretch="Fill"></Image>
<Image Source="Assets/远程问诊.png" Width="680" Height="280" Margin="1103,269,137,531" ></Image>
<Image Source="Assets/远程审方.png" Width="680" Height="280" Margin="1103,582,137,218" ></Image>
<Image Source="Assets/LOGO占位.png" Width="222" Height="56" Margin="36,34,1649,979"></Image>
<Image Source="Assets/竖线.png" Width="6" Height="40" Margin="283,42,1607,984"></Image>
<TextBlock Width="367" Height="48" Margin="338,49,1215,983" FontFamily="FangSong" FontSize="36" Text="医保结算系统 V1.0"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

Why are my non-background images being clipped?

Comment: You didn't showed any source code

Comment: Please read [ask], then [edit] your question. Include your code as a [mcve].

Comment: I changed it, please take a look the question please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `Margin` attribute on *all* the images. Then comment out all images except for one. Then Run the app. Does the image show correctly?

If so go to the next image. If not, verify that nothing is "clipping" the image in some way. Ask these questions:

- Do you have enough screen space for the image?
- Do you have the proper height and width set for the image?
- Is the `Grid` set to properly place images in their own `row`s and `column`s with appropriate sizes?
- Only use `Margin` to lightly move images within the `Grid`. Anything above `10` frankly should not be used and the `Grid` should properly place an image instead of high margin values.

Adjusting the image as such should allow you to properly place images on the screen.

Comment: When working in Visual Studio's designer and changing the grid. VS, behind the scenes, moves stuff visually around the grid changes by adding to `Margin` values. It looks right visually at that time, but really does not do a favor to the developer in the long run. Seeing your large `Margin` values suggested that was the issue. By following my advice, it should help you resolve it all. :-)

Comment: yes, it's resolved, thank you again for your responds!